# Socket.io emmitting an extra time each refresh (node.js)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Perhaps my logic is completely wrong, but as far as I know it should only emit once. Basically what is happening on load it will emit once. A refresh will make it emit twice, then three times, then 4 times. So on and so forth.

Found out: If i logout and relog, it keeps increasing.

EDIT: Okay so instead of the session user, I went and passed a random number through the emit just to make sure it was emitting more than once, and each number is different, so it is indeed triggering more than once.

Main socket.io file

```
const loadup = require("../funcs/loadup");
module.exports = io => {
  io.sockets.on("connect", socket => {
    loadup(socket);
  });
};
```

Loadup file:

```
module.exports = socket => {
  let session = socket.handshake.session;
  socket.emit("load up", session.user);
};
```

Route:

```
// Game route
app.get("/game", (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    let gameMainSocket = require("./sock/game-main-socket")(io);
    res.render("game", req.session.user);
  } else {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```

Emit event client side:

```
socket.on("load up", data => {
  console.log("Hello");
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I think you should declare your gameMainSocket outside the route

Comment: Yup, I just figured that out! Thanks. I wanted to kind of force it to only connect in the game route, but its not a huge deal as the game route only connect client side anyways.

Comment: yes if you keep gameMainSocket inside then it will create a listener every time

Answer (score 0):

I removed
`let gameMainSocket = require("./sock/game-main-socket")(io);`
Outside of the route, which fixed the problem.